# golang template - how are the semantics for default

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm

Looking at helm charts, there is often something like:

```
{{- default .Chart.Name .Values.nameOverride | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
```

I could not find anything about the default *function(?)* in the template docs:

https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/

What is the semantics of it? Are there any kind of arguments possible?

Comment: `default` is not a defined function (by default), most likely it is registered as a custom function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It comes from the library [sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/), which is [used](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/charts.md#templates-and-values) by Helm. Quoting the [docs](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/):

```
default "foo" .Bar
```

> In the above, if .Bar evaluates to a non-empty
>   value, it will be used. But if it is empty, foo will be returned
>   instead.